# How do I regenerate troops / fighters / bombers?

Tags: endless-space

I just invaded a system and lost some of my landing troops, e.g. my ship details shows `Troops: 1/2`. How do I regenerate those? I don't seem to be able to repair or retrofit the ships.

If the answer is "just wait", how long does it take? And do I have to be in friendly systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far for unscientific observation during gameplay, it looks like it regenerates by itself. It feels like this regeneration is indeed faster in owned systems.

It's pretty quick in any case, like 1 unit regeneration every 2-3 turns.